# Real silicon atom structure?

Tags: atoms, electronics

Text books say that a pure silicon atom has four electrons in its outermost orbit. 
How do the scientists know it has four electrons?

Answer (score 2):

One form of evidence is [the ionization energies of silicon](http://www.webelements.com/silicon/atoms.html).  Nth ionization energy is the energy needed to remove the nth electron.  There is a big jump going from the 4th ionization energy (~4000 kJ/mol) to the 5th ionization energy (~16000 kJ/mol).

Another form of evidence is the compounds silicon makes.  Silicon forms $\mathrm{SiH}_4$, $\mathrm{SiF}_4$, $\mathrm{SiCl}_4$ and other compounds that imply 4 valence shell electrons.

Answer (score 1):

We know that a bare silicon nucleus has electric charge +14$e$.

Electrons around an atomic nucleus don't follow any old orbit they wish, like planets  or comets orbiting the sun, but occupy [quantum-mechanical orbitals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital).  Each orbital is like a "slot" that can hold two electrons with opposite spins; after the slot is filled, the next electron in the atom has to occupy a different orbital.  The number of slots in each orbital depends on how much angular momentum the electrons in it carry:
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
\text{Orbital name} & \text{Angular momentum }\ell & \text{Number of slots}
\\
s & 0 & 1 \\
p & 1 & 3 \\
d & 2 & 5 \\
f & 3 & 7 \\
\vdots & n & 2n+1
\end{array}
$$
The shape of the [periodic table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_table) tells you which order the electrons prefer to fill up the orbitals.  If you started with a bare silicon nucleus and added electrons one at a time,

- the first two would fill up the 1s orbital, like in helium
- the next two would fill up the 2s orbital, like in beryllium
- the next six would fill up the 2p orbital, like in neon
- the next two would fill up the 3s orbital, like in magnesium
- the last two would live in the 3p orbital.

Most of the evidence for why the periodic table has this structure comes from chemistry, rather than physics.  DavePhD gives a couple of good examples.

Answer (score 0):

Early, while the periodic table of the elements was explored by [Mendeleev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dmitri_Mendeleev), it was already known that it can have nearly always 4 bonding. The source of this knowledge was at this time the analysis of the mass ratios of its compounds.

Later, after the [Bohr model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr_model) was developed, in the times of the modern [quantum chemistry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_chemistry) it is interpreted as it has 4 valency electrons. That means, 4 of its electrons is capable to participate in chemical bonds. Behind this knowledge are various approximations (f.e. [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born%E2%80%93Oppenheimer_approximation) or [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variational_method_%28quantum_mechanics%29)) to solve the very complex calculations of the electrons.